# Единственный слушатель для нескольких EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Есть вот такой некрасивый код:

```
passwordEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {
            if(passwordEditText.getText().length() < 8 || emailEditText.getText().length() < 6 ||
                    !emailEditText.getText().toString().contains("@") || inputRegistrationUsernameEditText.getText().length() < 5) {
                registrationButton.setClickable(false);
                registrationButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_selector_disabled));
            }
            else if (passwordEditText.getText().length() > 7 && emailEditText.getText().length() > 4 &&
                    emailEditText.getText().toString().contains("@") && inputRegistrationUsernameEditText.getText().length() > 3) {
                registrationButton.setClickable(true);
                registrationButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_selector));
            }
        }
    });

    emailEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {
            if(passwordEditText.getText().length() < 8 || emailEditText.getText().length() < 6 ||
                    !emailEditText.getText().toString().contains("@") || inputRegistrationUsernameEditText.getText().length() < 5) {
                registrationButton.setClickable(false);
                registrationButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_selector_disabled));
            }
            else if (passwordEditText.getText().length() > 7 && emailEditText.getText().length() > 4 &&
                    emailEditText.getText().toString().contains("@") && inputRegistrationUsernameEditText.getText().length() > 3) {
                registrationButton.setClickable(true);
                registrationButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_selector));
            }
        }
    });

    inputRegistrationUsernameEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {
            if(passwordEditText.getText().length() < 8 || emailEditText.getText().length() < 6 ||
                    !emailEditText.getText().toString().contains("@") || inputRegistrationUsernameEditText.getText().length() < 5) {
                registrationButton.setClickable(false);
                registrationButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_selector_disabled));
            }
            else if (passwordEditText.getText().length() > 7 && emailEditText.getText().length() > 4 &&
                    emailEditText.getText().toString().contains("@") && inputRegistrationUsernameEditText.getText().length() > 3) {
                registrationButton.setClickable(true);
                registrationButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_selector));
            }
        }
    });
```

Слушатели выполняют одну и ту же функцию. Можно ли объединить их в один для всех EditText? Извините за непонимание принципов ООП.

Comment: сделайте свой класс который extends TextWatcher, везде проставляете его и там вам полная свобода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкретно в вашем случае, это можно. Так как он везде одинаковый. 
Проблема данного слушателя в том что он не может идентифицировать того, где случилось событие и нужно проверять все.

Можно сделать как предложили выше. 
Либо сделайте для вашей Activity `implements TextWatcher`
После этого AndroidStudio предложит вам добавить методы:

```
@Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

 @Override
 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                          int before, int count) {
    if(passwordEditText.getText().length() < 8 || emailEditText.getText().length() < 6 ||
            !emailEditText.getText().toString().contains("@") || inputRegistrationUsernameEditText.getText().length() < 5) {
        registrationButton.setClickable(false);
        registrationButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_selector_disabled));
    }
    else if (passwordEditText.getText().length() > 7 && emailEditText.getText().length() > 4 &&
            emailEditText.getText().toString().contains("@") && inputRegistrationUsernameEditText.getText().length() > 3) {
        registrationButton.setClickable(true);
        registrationButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_selector));
    }
}
```

а в главном методе

```
passwordEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);
emailEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);
inputRegistrationUsernameEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если все одинаково, то почему бы не ввести локальную переменную:

```
    TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int count, int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                              int before, int count) {
        if(passwordEditText.getText().length() < 8 || emailEditText.getText().length() < 6 ||
                !emailEditText.getText().toString().contains("@") || inputRegistrationUsernameEditText.getText().length() < 5) {
            registrationButton.setClickable(false);
            registrationButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_selector_disabled));
        }
        else if (passwordEditText.getText().length() > 7 && emailEditText.getText().length() > 4 &&
                emailEditText.getText().toString().contains("@") && inputRegistrationUsernameEditText.getText().length() > 3) {
            registrationButton.setClickable(true);
            registrationButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_selector));
        }
    }
};
passwordEditText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
emailEditText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
inputRegistrationUsernameEditText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```